# ASP.NET MVC2 C# - Easy Question

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

```
    var categoryModel = AfvClassifiedsDB.Categories.Include("Listings")
            .Single(c => c.Title == categoryName);

        var viewModel = new ClassifiedsBrowseViewModel
        {
            Category = categoryModel,
            Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList(),
            DateListed = 
        };
```

I am retrieving some results from a database and then declaring them in a ViewModel.

I want to give DateListed (part of the view model) a value. This value is part of listings. I however, want this value to be in a specific date format: ".ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");"

Just a bit stuck as to why I am unable to get a value from listings.

Many Thanks, 
J

Edited to add full ActionMethod:

```
 public ActionResult ViewCategory(string categoryName, string searchCriteria = "Price")
    {
        // Retrieve Category and its associated Listings from the database
        var categoryModel = AfvClassifiedsDB.Categories.Include("Listings")
            .Single(c => c.Title == categoryName);

        var viewModel = new ClassifiedsBrowseViewModel();
        viewModel.Category = categoryModel;
        viewModel.Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList();
        viewModel.DateListed = viewModel.Listings.First().DateListed.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");

        switch(searchCriteria)
        {
            case "Title":
                viewModel.Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.Title).ToList();
                break;
            case "Price":
                viewModel.Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList();
                break;
            case "FuelType":
                viewModel.Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.FuelType).ToList();
                break;
            case "Transmission": 
                viewModel.Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.Transmission).ToList();
                break;
            default:
                viewModel.Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.DateListed).ToList();
                break;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: You say you're "unable to get a value from listings" but you haven't said what you've tried or what happened when you tried it.

Comment: Some clarity - what value is part of listings? also which value from listings do you want?

Comment: I'm a little confused - is your problem that you can't get a `DateTime` property from `categoryModel.Listings` or that you can't get it from `categoryModel` ? Why is the format string for the `DateTime` an issue?

Comment: I apologise if my description wasn't clear. I am trying to populate the DateTime model from the database query above. However, when I go to populate the DateListed model I was expecting to be able to do something like: DateListed = categoryModel.Listings.DateListed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a date listed property on objects within Listings

```
DateListed = categoryModel.Listings.First().DateListed.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

Comment: @jharley1 - glad it worked. if the answer is indeed correct, please mark as such

Comment: Hey Ahmed, both the solutions yourself and danny provided worked. Problem was with the section: .ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") the error was: "No overload for method 'to string' takes one argument.

Comment: @jharley1 - the assumption is that DateListed is a DateTime object.

Comment: Hey Ahmad, I have just checked the model and DateListed was a string, I have updated the model from the database but seem to still be getting the same issue ("DOH").

Comment: Here is my full viewModel: public class ClassifiedsBrowseViewModel
    {
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public List<Listing> Listings { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateListed { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @jharley - whats the definition for categoryModel and Listings. PLease update the question with this info

Comment: @Ahmad - I have updated the question to include the full Action Method.

Comment: @jharley1 - whats the purpose of of the `DateListed` field? what is it supposed to show relation to the `List<Listings>`? Do you want one DateTime string or a list of DateTime formatted strings?

Answer (score 0):

there is a great listing of all the different types on date-time string formatting in this post http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

hopefully this will help

paul

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your data looks like but shouldn't this do the trick?

```
DateListed = categoryModel.DateListed.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use property initializer here. Assign values step by step:

```
var viewModel = new ClassifiedsBrowseViewModel();
viewModel.Category = categoryModel;
viewModel.Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList();
viewModel.DateListed = viewModel.Listings.Select(item=>item.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")).ToList();
```

A simple explanation:

```
class Person
{
   public int ID { get;set; }
   public string Name { get;set; }
}
var p = new Person { ID=1, Name="test1" }; //ok
var another = new Person
    {
       ID = 2,
       Name = "test"+ID         //compile error
    };
var again = new Person();
again.ID = 3;
again.Name = "test"+again.ID; //of course it's correct
```

Comment: Hey Danny, good call, all working except when you convert the item into a string and try and set the date format, it says 'To String' takes one argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the call of `Single` instead of `First`

I would use code like this:

```
    var categoryModel = AfvClassifiedsDB.Categories.Include("Listings")
            .First(c => c.Title == categoryName);

        var viewModel = new ClassifiedsBrowseViewModel
        {
            Category = categoryModel,
            Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList(),
            DateListed = categoryModel.Listings.DateListed.ToString("("MMMM dd, yyyy")
        };
```

Single return a list of length 1, and First returns the first object from the list.